# Anottations in Spring MVC/Maven aren't working

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-mvc, annotations

I experiencing this problem when try to access  local host uri http://localhost:8080/spring/olaMundoSpring it is returning in browser:

> STATUS 404 The requested resource is not available.

And:

> *No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring/olaMundoSpring] in >DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'.*

*spring-context.xml* seems to be okay:

> set 05, 2016 9:45:24 PM >org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader >loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB->INF/spring-context.xml]

**Controller:**

```
package br.com.jayybe.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Controle {

  @RequestMapping("/olaMundoSpring")
  public String execute() {
      System.out.println("Executando a lógica com Spring MVC");
      return "ok";
  }
}
```

[image: IDE Eclipse DIR]

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
      <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>
             WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
          </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.jayybe.spring" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jayybe</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
              </dependency>

              <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
              </dependency>
              <!-- Servlet -->
              <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
              </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your test. What I would try is set a breakpoint in [DispatcherServlet.doDispatch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#doDispatch-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-) and start from there.

Comment: What should I expect to test/debug there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your annotation like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/olaMundoSpring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Change your component scan:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.*" />
```

And don't use a name with white spaces for the servlet-mapping

Comment: I did what you said, it didn't worked, but I don't know I, I reinstalled eclipse, re-imported project and it worked.... why we shoudn't use white spaces in servlet-mapping?